# Sybase STR-function in Oracle

Tags: string, oracle, function, sybase

is there an equivalent to Sybase's STR-Function, which converts a number to string

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Str.htm

in Oracle? I could not find one. If there isn't, is there an elegant way to reproduce it?

Thanks very much!

Edit: for example:

```
str(123.56,30,10)
```

in Sybase gives a string of total length 30, exactly 10 places behind the decimal and filled with spaces on the left, so the result is

```
                123.5600000000
```

Comment: I think you can use `to_char` with an specified format. Plus add some data to your question and the desired result. Then i can help with to_char function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select to_char(123.56, '99999999999999999999.00000000000')
from dual;
```

or, more generically (substitute 30 and 10 respectively as required):

```
select to_char(123.56, lpad(rpad('.',10,'0'),30,'9'))
from dual;
```

Note: the string length will be 31 to allow room for the possible "-" (negative) sign.

Answer (score 0):

As oracle doesn't have such especific function you will need to create one. So, this one here will help you. Maybe it need some improvment to check wheter the len is bigger than the number of decimals. But it is a good start.

```
create or replace function str( num in number, 
                                len in integer, 
                                decsLength in integer ) return varchar2 is
   decSep nls_database_parameters.value%type;
   befSep varchar2(255);
   aftSep varchar2(255); 
   finalStr varchar2(255);
begin

    --this gets the decimal separator, It depends on the 
    --database configuration.
    select substr(value, 2, 1) into decSep 
      from nls_database_parameters
     where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';

    select substr( to_char(num), 1, 
                   decode( instr(to_char(num), decSep),              
                           0,
                           length(to_char(num)),
                           instr(to_char(num), decSep)-1) ) 
             into befSep from dual;

    select decode( instr(to_char(num), decSep), 
                   0, 
                   '', 
                   substr(to_char(num),
                          instr(to_char(num),decSep)+1)) 
           into aftSep from dual;

    if instr(to_char(num),decSep) > 0 then
        finalStr := lpad( befSep, len-(decsLength+1), ' ' ) 
                       || decSep || rpad(aftSep,decsLength, '0');
    else
        finalStr := lpad(befSep, len, ' ' );
    end if;

    return finalStr; 

end str;
```

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name's Solution seems to work fine for me and is very simple. However, thanks for showing me how you made this function!

Comment: I've create this function just because you ask for a similar function, which will work for every case when you change the parameters. I know the to_char function but it is fixed with the masks.